# Failed to Parse Error - What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, shell, parsing

This is the line with the "Failed to Parse Error" -> var label = package.getComment() && package.getComment() : 'N/A'

The rest of the code...
    var script = '/home/paulomacedo/jd2/JD_HOME/jdownloader-postprocess.sh'

```
var path = package.getDownloadFolder() 
var name = package.getName() 
var label = package.getComment() && package.getComment() : 'N/A' 
var links = package.getDownloadLinks() ? package.getDownloadLinks() : []

function isReallyFinished() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].getArchive() != null && links[i].getExtractionStatus() != "SUCCESSFUL" || !package.isFinished()) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

if (isReallyFinished()) {
    var command = [script, path, name, label, 'PACKAGE_FINISHED']
    log(command)
    log(callSync(command))
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask that question on CodeReview : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SuperPeanut Code Review is for asking about [best practices etc. on **working code**.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MikeC My bad sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
var label = package.getComment() && package.getComment() : 'N/A' 
//                                                       ^
```

You properly want to use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var label = package.getComment() ? package.getComment() : 'N/A'
```

Or `a && b || c`:

```
var label = package.getComment() && package.getComment() || 'N/A'
```